# How to display an object that contains another object in thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

Hi I struggling to build a proper view in case, when I want to display the product entity, which is in a many-to-many relation with the category. The problem starts with the nested category. I have an error: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "category.name" (productList: 31) I will be very grateful for your help in solving this problem

View:

```
<tbody>
            <tr data-th-each="product : ${products}">
                <!--<td><input hidden="hidden" name="id" th:value="${product.id}" /></td>-->
                <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
                <td th:each="category : ${product.categories}"></td>
                <td th:text="${category.name}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.shippingWeight}"></td>
                <td th:text="${product.quantity}"></td>
                <td>delete</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Entities:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "product_id")
private Long id;
private String name;
private BigDecimal price;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "products")
private List<Category> categories=new ArrayList<>();
private double shippingWeight;
private boolean isAvailable;
private String description;
private int quantity;
@Transient
private MultipartFile image;
```

Category:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "category_id")
private Long id;

private String name;

private String description;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "join_category_product", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", referencedColumnName = "category_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "product_id")})
private List<Product> products=new ArrayList<>();
@Transient
private MultipartFile image;
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/productList")
public String productList(Model model) {
    List<Product> product = productService.getProducts();
    model.addAttribute("products",product);
    return "productList";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the Thymeleaf can understand the scope of your variables.  In your post, you have `category.name` outside of the for loop.  If `categories` is a property of `product`, you can do something like:

```
        <tr th:each="product : ${products}">
            <td th:text="${product.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.price}"></td>
            <td>
                <th:block th:each="category : ${product.categories}">
                     <th:block th:text="${category.name}">[category name]</th:block> 
                     <br>
                </th:block>
            </td>
            <td th:text="${product.description}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.shippingWeight}"></td>
            <td th:text="${product.quantity}"></td>
            <td>delete</td>
        </tr>
```

If a product doesn't have a category, note that the above will still create a `<td>`.  This is likely what you want.

**Aside:** it would also make sense to supply default values between your tags.  This way, you can open up the file directly in a browser (without a container) and still see how it would lay out.  This is a huge reason to use Thymeleaf.  I included this with `[category name]` example above.

Otherwise, you can do the shorter version:

`<td>[[${product.name}]]</td>`

Comment: Thank you very much bphilipnyc